Django Project Depolyment in Windows Server using Apache
I have installed python 3.12, Django, Apache, and tested all without pasting my project inside htdocs and that run. Now in htdocs, I have kept my project two folder core and myenv.
Inside core main project files C:\Apache24\htdocs\core\core\wsgi.py
httpd.conf.
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/Python312/python312.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Program Files/Python312/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp312-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Program Files/Python312"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/core/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Program Files/Python312/Lib/site-packages"
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/core/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
Alias /static "C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/static/"
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/static/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
//////
Listen 3080
ServerName example.com:80

But when I start Apache, and run its shows error.
Internal Server Error:
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
and in logs>error:

mod_wsgi (pid=1648): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/core/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):\rFile "C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r line 16, in <module>\r
File "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r
[Thu May 02 16:40:44.634611 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1648:tid 1228] [client ::1:50356]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'\r
mod_wsgi (pid=1648): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/core/core/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost:3080/

I want to run my project in windows server with Apache, but for these error it is not running.

Can you please [edit] and format your question properly? Use code fences ``` or indent your code and error messages by four spaces. Thank you.
